# How can I use my Git at school

Tags: php, git, ftp, bitbucket, collaboration

We're starting a new project on school. Our assignment is to build a fully functioning web app in PHP with the requirement of using a database. I'm working in a group of three people, so collaboration is a must.

Instead of uploading files to our FTP-server, I was planning to do it via BitBucket. Deploy can automatically upload the commits to our server via FTP. This already works.

Creating, editing, renaming and deleting files can be done by the online interface. However, copying and uploading files isn't possible via ButBucket.org. These last two will be needed for building the project.

Here comes the problem; our school has a strict policy for working at the school network. The computers at our school use Windows 7. We can't install programs, because we don't have administrator rights. We can run .exe files, but only from our home directory, which is only around 100MB in size. Consequence is that we can't install either Git or SourceTree (or a similair program).

We don't have WiFi in our school either, so using our own devices isn't an option.

What I'm looking for is a solution to manage our Git repository on these school computers.

I'm hoping someone as experience with something like this or just has a more creative mind than I have.

Comment: Something like https://github.com/sheabunge/GitPortable maybe?

Comment: I would talk to the CS(?) professors and make a strong use-case / argument. It would be 'best' to get supporting IT. If the school has a separate CS computer lab this should be relatively easy for them to accommodate..

Comment: Either that, or do all your development on a remote machine and SSH / remote-desktop into it from school.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way to access Git without internet but you can `clone` the repository to a portable medium and copy it to your computer later.
For clone your project use this command:

```
git clone /path/to/source-repository /another/path/to/destination-repository
```

Comment: School computers are hard wired he said.